# Add grid lines to r plot() so that code can be used by any group within a dataset

Tags: r, plot, graphics

I have a dataset that has grouped data, I filter the data so that I can plot a specific category. I have code written so that I can plot whichever group I want without having to change any of the graphical parameters.

The only problem is I can't figure out a good way to automate the grid lines/the y-axis spacing. I'm currently using abline() but the scale of the yaxis isn't very intuitive making it hard to read. I tried using grid() but they were offset from the y-axis labels.

Below is a sample dataset and plotting code. The issue is that the code I use to determine the interval between the ticks (`data_tick_interval`) doesn't always work for each group ( the `/10) * 10` part of the code needs to be changed between groups). And when it does work the scale of the y-axis isn't very intuitive making it hard to determine the value of the data.

I'm trying to find a more elegant/efficient way of determining the interval between y-axis spacing so that the only thing that needs to be changed in the group.

```
data <- structure(list(Year = c(2005, 2006, 2007, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2005, 
                        2006, 2007, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2005, 2006, 2007, 
                        2005, 2006, 2007, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2005, 2006, 
                        2007, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2005, 
                        2006, 2007, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2005, 2006, 2007, 
                        2005, 2006, 2007, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2005, 2006, 
                        2007, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2005, 
                        2006, 2007, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2005, 2006, 2007
), group = c("K0A", "K0A", "K0A", "K0B", "K0B", "K0B", "K0C", 
             "K0C", "K0C", "K0E", "K0E", "K0E", "K0A", "K0A", "K0A", "K0B", 
             "K0B", "K0B", "K0C", "K0C", "K0C", "K0E", "K0E", "K0E", "K0A", 
             "K0A", "K0A", "K0B", "K0B", "K0B", "K0C", "K0C", "K0C", "K0E", 
             "K0E", "K0E", "K0A", "K0A", "K0A", "K0B", "K0B", "K0B", "K0C", 
             "K0C", "K0C", "K0E", "K0E", "K0E", "K0A", "K0A", "K0A", "K0B", 
             "K0B", "K0B", "K0C", "K0C", "K0C", "K0E", "K0E", "K0E", "K0A", 
             "K0A", "K0A", "K0B", "K0B", "K0B", "K0C", "K0C", "K0C", "K0E", 
             "K0E", "K0E", "K0A", "K0A", "K0A", "K0B", "K0B", "K0B", "K0C", 
             "K0C", "K0C", "K0E", "K0E", "K0E"), city = c("Hamilton", "Hamilton", 
                                                          "Hamilton", "Hamilton", "Hamilton", "Hamilton", "Hamilton", "Hamilton", 
                                                          "Hamilton", "Hamilton", "Hamilton", "Hamilton", "Kitchner", "Kitchner", 
                                                          "Kitchner", "Kitchner", "Kitchner", "Kitchner", "Kitchner", "Kitchner", 
                                                          "Kitchner", "Kitchner", "Kitchner", "Kitchner", "Peterborough", 
                                                          "Peterborough", "Peterborough", "Peterborough", "Peterborough", 
                                                          "Peterborough", "Peterborough", "Peterborough", "Peterborough", 
                                                          "Peterborough", "Peterborough", "Peterborough", "Sudbury", "Sudbury", 
                                                          "Sudbury", "Sudbury", "Sudbury", "Sudbury", "Sudbury", "Sudbury", 
                                                          "Sudbury", "Sudbury", "Sudbury", "Sudbury", "Toronto", "Toronto", 
                                                          "Toronto", "Toronto", "Toronto", "Toronto", "Toronto", "Toronto", 
                                                          "Toronto", "Toronto", "Toronto", "Toronto", "Waterloo", "Waterloo", 
                                                          "Waterloo", "Waterloo", "Waterloo", "Waterloo", "Waterloo", "Waterloo", 
                                                          "Waterloo", "Waterloo", "Waterloo", "Waterloo", "Windsor", "Windsor", 
                                                          "Windsor", "Windsor", "Windsor", "Windsor", "Windsor", "Windsor", 
                                                          "Windsor", "Windsor", "Windsor", "Windsor"), var1 = c(188, 148, 
                                                                                                                0, 128, 344, 2920, 553, 321, 515, 544, 575, 8000, 162, 409, 109, 
                                                                                                                195, 436, 552, 481, 162, 178, 455, 455, 438, 272, 97, 125, 388, 
                                                                                                                429, 4480, 458, 465, 283, 455, 366, 394, 425, 218, 278, 505, 
                                                                                                                515, 175, 65, 414, 447, 553, 226, 510, 2, 58, 513, 355, 447, 
                                                                                                                187, 154, 447, 503, 251, 563, 252, 513, 177, 156, 556, 460, 515, 
                                                                                                                119, 279, 247, 291, 501, 445, 497, 351, 90, 126, 181, 0, 344, 
                                                                                                                56700, 70, 338, 238, 317)), row.names = c(NA, -84L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                               "tbl", "data.frame"))

data_of_interest <- data %>% filter (group == "K0B") # change group

data_min <- floor(min(data_of_interest$var1) / 10) * 10
data_max <- ceiling(max(data_of_interest$var1) / 10) * 10
data_tick_interval <- floor(((data_max - data_min)/10)/10) * 10 # this is how I'm determining the space between the ticks
data_plot <- data.frame(format(xtabs(data_of_interest$var1 ~ data_of_interest$Year + data_of_interest$city, data_of_interest))) 
data_time <- seq(as.Date("2005-01-01"), length = 3, by = "year") 

plot (data_time, data_plot$Hamilton,type = "b", pch = 19, col = "red", ylab = "", xlab = "", axes = F, ylim = c(data_min, data_max))
lines(data_time, data_plot$Kitchner, type = "b", pch = 4, col = "blue")
lines(data_time, data_plot$Peterborough, type = "b", pch = 15, col = "black")
lines(data_time, data_plot$Sudbury, type = "b", pch = 5, col = "darkgreen")
lines(data_time, data_plot$Toronto, type = "b", pch = 8, col = "pink")
lines(data_time, data_plot$Waterloo, type = "b", pch = 9, col = "purple")
lines(data_time, data_plot$Windsor, type = "b", pch = 14, col = "brown")
mtext("Time (annual)", side = 1, line = 3, cex = 1)
mtext("People", side = 2, line = 3.2, cex = 1)
mtext("Cities", side = 3, line = 0.5, cex = 1, col = "black")
axis(1, data_time, format(data_time, "%Y"), cex = 1.5, lwd = 0.5)
axis(2, at = seq(data_min, data_max, data_tick_interval), cex = 1.5, lwd = 0.5, las = 1)
abline(h = seq(data_min, data_max, by = data_tick_interval), lwd = 0.1, lty = 3, col ="grey50")
```

Comment: @shafee the code of the plot is already included in the codeblock after the data.

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't notice. Thanks @AdamQuek, for pointing this out.

Comment: What if you use `pretty(data_of_interest$var1, n = 11)` to identify the appropriate tick mark placement?

Comment: @DaveArmstrong, thanks, this is the best solution so far.